# Unable to provide text to input field in reactjs form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm quite new to react so excuse me if this comes across as a stupid question.

I'm trying to submit my form using `Meteor` and `React`. When I click submit button I get undefined undefined but that is only because I cannot type into the input fields. Can't figure it. Here is my code.

At the moment the only thing `onSubmit` is doing is providing a log.

```
    export default class AddDeal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set the state
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      description: ''
    };

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.name, this.state.age);
  }

  handleChange(e) {


    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add Deal</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <label><input value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="title"/></label>
        <label><input value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="description" /></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handle change function, change `event` to `e` or vice versa. You are accepting an e but then using something called event. These variable names should be the same.

```
handleChange(e) {


  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is [e.target.name] getting all the input fields?

Comment: when a change happens on an input you are calling that handleChange function, so e.target.name will get the name field of the currently changed input element

Comment: no worries, if this fixed your problem, please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

You got nothing wrong besides a few typos. In the handleChange method, you're using `event` to refer to the event object, although it is defined in the argument list as `e`. Besides that, in the `onSubmit` method, you're logging the `name` and `age` attributes of the state, while your form fields are for attributes called `title` and `description`.

I point that out in [this pen](https://codepen.io/valbrand/pen/JNWVMR)